# Angular singleton

Tags: angular, service, singleton, provider

I have a singleton declared in app.module.ts: `providers: [UserClaimsService],`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserClaimsService {
  public user: User;
}
```

When I assign something to the variable user:

```
this._userClaimsService.user = user;
```

and I'll do console.log in the component where I assigned it, everything works. But when I do console.log in another component, it doesn't work. Why? Another component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserClaimsService } from '../../services/user-claims.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _userClaimsService: UserClaimsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this._userClaimsService.user);
  }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where did you assign "this._userClaimsService.user = user;". Make sure that you have assigned this user object before logging it in HomeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Use behavior subject. set the value of user using a behavior subject and subscribe the value change from home.component.ts. In that way changed value you can get.

Its not working because when the home component getting created UserClaimsService doesn't have the updated value. ngOnInit lifecycle of both components getting executed same time. So when you are setting the value in one component, home component is already loaded by then and in that there is no value for user. To avoid this situation you need to use behavior subject.

follow the below example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Looks like order of execution. Add a log just before you set your user property. This will clarify what's going on. As your HomeComponent is likely created before you set the property and therefore it's ngOnInit is running before you set the property.
As previously suggested you may want to use a Subject to provide a reactive solution but depending on what you are trying to achieve a simple getter in the component could be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OnInit, I did AfterViewInit and it works. Thanks!